# Props not being passed to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to pass some values as props to one component that I have 
(Product).

It seems when I console.log(JSON.stringify(props)), the result is: {}.

What can i possibly may be doing wrong?

```
export default class ProductList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            productList: [],
        }
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/products/getSixProducts?pageNumber=1')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(((products) => products.map((product, index) => {
                this.state.productList.push(
                    <Product
                        key={index}
                        id={product._id}
                        brandId={product.brandId}
                        image={product.image}
                        price={product.price}
                        priceDiscounted={product.priceDiscounted}
                        subtitle={product.subtitle}
                    />)
            })))

            .catch(this.setState({ productList: [-1] }))
...
```

This is my Product constructor:

```
...
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: props.id,
            brandId: props.brandId,
            subtitle: props.subtitle,
            price: props.price,
            priceDiscounted: props.priceDiscounted,
            image: { productImage }
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
    }
...
```

Comment: Maybe `static getDerivedStateFromProps()` is what you are looking for? See it in [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

Comment: Word of advice. `componentWillMount` is deprecated for the most part. `componentDidMount` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: being that the fetch is asynchronous the element will render before the productList is updated, you may see problems such as productList[0].prop is undefined as a result. to get around this add an isLoading property to the components state and render something different if isloading is false

Comment: Also, why do you set the props as state properties in `Product` component? Is there any reason not using them directly?

Answer (score 1):

As you are performing API call which is asynchronous in nature, the response may return after the child component might have been rendered.

Also best possible way to perform API call, is to use `componentDidMount` lifecycle. `componentWillMount` has been deprecated and not advised to use for asynchronous operations(i.e. Network calls).

So `constructor()` gets called only once on any component. The lifecycle you need is [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) which always checks for new/updated `props` and it's `state`.

This will look like in `Product` Component:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps !== this.props) {
     console.log('updated Props',this.props); // You can check this.props will change if they are updated
        this.setState({
            id: this.props.id,
            brandId: this.props.brandId,
            subtitle: this.props.subtitle,
            price: this.props.price,
            priceDiscounted: this.props.priceDiscounted,
        })
    }
}
```